# Comment out some part of a line in matlab function

Tags: matlab, comments

As the question suggests I want to comment out some part of a line in MATLAB.

Also I want to comment out some part of a line not till the end of line.

Reason for this is, I have to try two different versions of a line and I don't want to replicate the line twice. I know it is easy to comment/uncomment if I replicate the line , But I want it this way.

Comment: I was just looking for this functionality too, being ready to use the `~` character to replace some unused variables but wanting to leave their names in place with a multiline comment like you'd see with say `function( ~ /* param1 */ , ~ /* param2 */ )` if I were doing C++, Java, or C#.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Within one line is not possible (afaik), but you can split up your term into multiple lines:

```
x=1+2+3 ... optional comments for each line
... * factorA ... can be inserted here
* factorB ...
+4;
```

Here `* factorA` is commented out and `* factorB` is used, resulting in the term `x=1+2+3*factorB+4`.

[The documentation contains a similar example, commenting out one part of an array](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comments.html):

```
header = ['Last Name, ',      ...
          'First Name, ',     ...
      ... 'Middle Initial, ', ...
          'Title']
```

Comment: That's an amazing abuse of the line continuation syntax. Docs seem to say it's okay though!

Comment: Daniel.... that's just cool LOL.  I knew that `...` commented out the rest of the line, but to use it this way is frightening and awesome at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is not possible. From `help '%'`:

```
%   Percent.  The percent symbol is used to begin comments.
    Logically, it serves as an end-of-line character. Any
    following text on the line is ignored or printed by the
    HELP system.
```

So just copy-paste the line, or write a tiny function so that it's easier to switch between versions.