# Can we add a statement in between MATLAB codes?

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to add statements in between the codes.
For example: If I have a code like this,

```
r(:,1) = a(:,1) - a(:,2);
```

Then can I write it as,

```
r(:,1) = a(:,1)("this is a constant") - a(:,2)("this is a variable");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comment out some part of a line in matlab function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205691/comment-out-some-part-of-a-line-in-matlab-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to comment those statements like this

```
r(:,1) = a(:,1) ... % this is a constant 
         - a(:,2); % this is a variable
```

for more information read [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Comments)

Answer (score -1):

Just as a sideremark to the very correct answer of *sudomakeinstall2*

In other programming languages, as e.g. Java you can do something like

```
myvar = 1 + /* some comment here */ 5;
```

Eventhough MATLAB knows something similar with `%{` ending with `%}`, **they only work for multiline comments**, so in the end, sudomakeinstall2s answer is the best I can think of.